# How to change user in the appmaker editor

Tags: google-app-maker

I created an App with the GSuite administrator account. But now when I go back I am my work user(rob) and have no access to the App I created.

If I then go to Google and switch accounts there is no issue for all other Google apps(drive, gmail etc) but Appmaker still shows me as rob.

How can I convince App Maker to work like all other Google apps and let me select the logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it happens because at this time App Maker doesn't provide users with account chooser widget like most other Google products. Here are some things to try to bypass this limitation:

- use different chrome instances for better accounts separation (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824) - I would highly recommend this approach. I have about 10 different accounts and this feature saves me tons of time and gives peace of mind
- use incognito window
- log out from other accounts (in theory, when you open AM it will ask you to choose an account and re-login)

Comment: the first option multiple accounts is how I am currently working, so it is a pity appmaker does not support that directly. In the end I have used incognito.